# Quarkus OpenShift Deployment On Local Machine

Tags: maven, kubernetes, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application that I am trying to deploy to OpenShift on my local. The CodeReady Containers VM for OpenShift is already running.
I am new to this type of setup and still learning. After much research and trying out a lot of suggestions, I have hit a wall.

I am running this command

```
./mvnw clean package -Dquarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true
```

The application builds, and when it gets to the step about Applied: BuildConfig, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor] Performing s2i binary build with jar on server: https://api.crc.testing:6443/ in namespace:audit-ms.
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor] Applied: ImageStream audit
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor] Found: ImageStream openjdk-11-rhel7 repository: registry.access.redhat.com/openjdk/openjdk-11-rhel7
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor] Applied: BuildConfig audit
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:30 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-12T14:51:09+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.7.3.Final:build (default) on project audit: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor#s2iBuildFromJar threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Execution of s2i build failed. See s2i output for more details
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor.s2iException(S2iProcessor.java:383)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor.s2iBuild(S2iProcessor.java:327)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor.lambda$s2iBuild$10(S2iProcessor.java:301)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor.s2iBuild(S2iProcessor.java:301)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor.createContainerImage(S2iProcessor.java:252)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor.s2iBuildFromJar(S2iProcessor.java:183)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:932)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
[ERROR] Caused by: io.dekorate.deps.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Can't instantiate binary build, due to error reading/writing stream. Can be caused if the output stream was closed by the server.
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl$1.writeTo(BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:237)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:72)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:134)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.openshift.client.internal.OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.intercept(OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.java:69)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:469)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:448)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl.fromInputStream(BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:251)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl.fromFile(BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:208)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl.fromFile(BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:65)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.s2i.deployment.S2iProcessor.s2iBuild(S2iProcessor.java:319)
[ERROR]     ... 26 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1052)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.deliver(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:342)
[ERROR]     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1264)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:79)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:180)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:179)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:42)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSink.write(Http1Codec.java:295)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okio.ForwardingSink.write(ForwardingSink.java:35)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor$CountingSink.write(CallServerInterceptor.java:149)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:179)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.okio.RealBufferedSink.writeAll(RealBufferedSink.java:107)
[ERROR]     at io.dekorate.deps.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl$1.writeTo(BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:235)
[ERROR]     ... 56 more
```

Please assist in what could be the error on deploying this application. I am probably missing a configuration.

My application.properties file looks like this:

```
quarkus.log.level= DEBUG
quarkus.mongodb.connection-string=mongodb://localhost:27017/audit
quarkus.mongodb.database=audit
quarkus.kubernetes-client.trust-certs=true
quarkus.s2i.base-jvm-image=registry.access.redhat.com/openjdk/openjdk-11-rhel7
quarkus.openshift.expose=true
```

Comment: Does a builder pod get created in the OpenShift namespace? If it does, does its log show anything of interest?

Comment: Actually, I wonder if it's just a timeout of some kind? Some of the image-pushing steps are pretty time-consuming, and if you're running OpenShift and the build on the same machine, that's likely to make the situation worse. If you repeat the deployment, does it fail in the same way every time?

Comment: It does fail the same way every time, and yes, I am running OpenShift and doing the build on the same machine. I wanted to test this locally before I push to a server. You would reckon I should install OpenShift on a separate machine and then do a build to push there?

Comment: FWIW I would suggest trying with the "getting-started" sample, just to rule out a problem in your application But when I've seen this exception, it's been on systems that were broken in some way -- under heavy load or just, well, broken. CRC is a heavy thing to run on a laptop. I find that I _can_ deploy Quarkus apps on my laptop, but it's not very reliable.